# Number of hair cycles in humans

Tags: genetics, hair

I've seen several websites claim the amount of hair cycles a follicle will go through is predetermined at around 25-30 complete cycles. Is there any genetic evidence to validate this claim? How can this even be determined apart from observationally seeing people lose hair as they age?

[Here](http://www.norgilcanada.com/en/services-and-treatments/natural-cycles-of-hair.html)'s a link referring to what I'm talking about:

> The number of hair growth cycles is limited: our hair will experience about 25 to 30 cycles like this during our lifetime.

Comment: note that is an individual follicle, we do grow new ones.

Comment: The link in this question is dead. :(